# .ToUniversalTime() Is Incorrect?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(1972, 4, 24, 0, 0, 0);
    Response.Write("dt: " + dt.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + "<br />");
    Response.Write("dt.Kind: " + dt.Kind.ToString() + "<br />");
    Response.Write("dt.ToUniversalTime(): " + dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt") + "<br />");
```

displays

```
dt: 4/24/1972 12:00:00 AM
dt.Kind: Unspecified
dt.ToUniversalTime(): 4/24/1972 7:00:00 AM
```

which is incorrect. April 24, 1972 at 12 PM Pacific is actually April 24, 1972 at 8 AM UTC.

I have confirmed the correct UTC conversion with iOS's internal UTC date conversation and www.timeanddate.com and the UTC time should be 8 AM.  Am I doing something wrong?

The server is running in "Pacific Time" timezone so ToUniversalTime should be converting from Pacific timezone to UTC since Unspecified is treated like Local.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: What do you mean by *Not right now it's not?* Why would the conversion from a point in time to UTC change based on what the *current* timezone is?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker The "point in time" that is being converted to UTC is created in the current timezone.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: thanks...I overlooked that the OP was using a date in 1972. I saw a month and day very close to the current month and day and skimmed past the year.

Comment: @BJMyers: That's true, but in 1972 that time zone's offset from UTC was -8, not -7. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on a machine that's not on Pacific Standard Time, you can see this behavior using the following code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1972, 4, 24, 0, 0, 0);    
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

Console.WriteLine (TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz));
// 4/24/1972 7:00:00 AM
```

If you look at [navy.mil's history of daylight saving time](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/daylight_time.php), you'll notice the following paragraph:

> The Uniform Time Act of 1966 provided standardization in the dates of
>   beginning and end of daylight time in the U.S. but allowed for local
>   exemptions from its observance. **The act provided that daylight time
>   begin on the last Sunday in April and end on the last Sunday in
>   October**, with the changeover to occur at 2 a.m. local time.

And then a little later on:

> In 1986, a law was passed that shifted the starting date of daylight
>   time to the first Sunday in April, beginning in 1987

So the DST switchover wasn't the *first* Sunday in April until 1987, but for some reason .NET is acting as if it was.

[Timeanddate.com's history of DST seems to agree](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/washington-dc?year=1972), and lists April 30, 1972 (the last Sunday in April) as the date clocks were turned forward one hour (to UTC-7).

Microsoft's DST adjustment rules for times before 1987 appear to be wrong ([and I'm not the only one who thinks so](http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/06/beware-daylight-saving-time-transitions-in-dot-net/)).

Here's what `TimeZoneInfo` lists as the rules for PST:

[image]

Basically, Microsoft has ignored the historical rules and chosen to use rules put into effect in 1987 for dates that happened before those rules even existed.

Essentially your date (in 1972) is being handled incorrectly by Microsoft's `TimeZoneInfo` adjustment rules.

If you're looking for a library that handles these types of time zone rules much better, check out [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/), which handles this particular case correctly:

```
var pacific = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Los_Angeles"];

LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(1972, 4, 24, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = pacific.AtStrictly(localDateTime);

DateTime utcDateTime = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();

Console.WriteLine(utcDateTime);
// 4/24/1972 8:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Great answer. I am surprised Microsoft shipped the framework with such a glaring bug.  Thank you for confirming and pointing me to Noda.

Comment: It's not necessarily a "bug" - it's just that Windows time zones don't have this level of historical accuracy.  Since .NET gets time zone data from Windows, it's limited by the range of data that Windows provides.  IANA time zones (used by Noda Time) have a much richer history, and thus are better suited for this sort of task.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Right, I understand that the behavior is caused by Windows time zone information, but I'd still consider it a bug. No matter the underlying cause, the user is attempting to convert between time zones and gets an incorrect result. The fact that the time zone information is retrieved from Windows shouldn't matter to the end user

Comment: Would it be better if it threw an exception?  Other than actually having all the data necessary to return a correct response, what would you expect it to do?

Comment: @MattJohnson: Rereading the documentation for `TimeZoneInfo` I can see why this wouldn't classify as a bug. `TimeZoneInfo` contains language that specifically ties it to the underlying operating system's time zones and doesn't make any guarantees about the accuracy of those time zones. I suppose a better thing to say is that conversions using `TimeZoneInfo` can be unreliable due to the incomplete nature of Windows' time zone information. I would say that it would be nice if `TimeZoneInfo` wasn't tied to the OS's time zones, but I'm sure that decision was made for good reason

Comment: Agreed - That would be nice.  Noda Time is the best bet in the mean time.  Thanks for recommending it! :)

Comment: Same thing here, France used to be UTC+1 in summer a long time ago, and moved to UTC+2 in 1976. But standard DateTime doesn't care :( Thanks for the information