# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc returns strange output for 1972 year

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm struggling with a strange DateTime conversion issue. For the "PST timezone", Dates starting with 1973 are working as expected, 8 hours difference from UTC (winter). But till 1973, the difference is 9 hours !! That looks very strange to me. Maybe I'm missing something.

The following code:

```
        var time = new DateTime(1972,12,30, 8,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Dawson");
        var converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, timeZoneInfo);
        Console.WriteLine($"Original UTC: {time}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Converted: {converted}");
```

outputs this output

> Original UTC: 12/30/72 8:00:00 AM
>
> Converted: 12/29/72 11:00:00 PM

What are the reason of this output and how to avoid this?

**Update:**
Changing from `America/Dawson` to `America/Los_Angeles` fixes the issue. Even if both `timeZoneInfo` points to `pacific standard time`.

Comment: 1972 was a leap year.  Dunno if that helps or not.

Comment: silly question, is it correct for every year?) maybe for 2000 for example ti will be 8 hours?

Comment: A quick search finds that Dawson stopped observing DST in 1972, if that changes anything? : https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada/dawson-creek?year=1972

Comment: See the comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957527/touniversaltime-is-incorrect)

Comment: How is this related to C# 8? The timezone information comes from the OS. Given that Windows *doesn't* use the IANA timezone names, I suspect you run this on Linux? This means the question itself has nothing to do with .NET or C#, the iANA timezone database itself contains different rules for `America/Dawson` and `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: There's on official `Pacific Standard Time` anyway, that's just a convenience name. Countries, states,cities change timezone rules all the time, which makes it impossible to use convenience names to track tz rules across time. The IANA TZ database contains all rules going back to the 1800s

Comment: `Changing from America/Dawson to America/Los_Angeles fixes the issue` no, this *broke* the code by using the wrong timezone. Keep in mind that *all* Linux systems and NodaTime in .NET/.NET Core use the IANA timezone database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For the "PST timezone"

PST isn't a time zone. It's usually used as an abbreviation for Pacific Standard Time, or UTC-8. If you mean "Pacific Time", varying between UTC-8 and UTC-7, that's still not a single time zone really - although there's a link from "US/Pacific" to "America/Los_Angeles".

The question is really: which *precise* location are you interested in when you're performing the conversion? Different parts of America that currently consider themselves as being on "Pacific Time" observe historically different rules - which is why you're seeing this behaviour.

> What are the reason of this output

America/Dawson had an offset of UTC-9 between 1965 and 1973, as you've observed. Basically, you're observing reality - it's just not what you expected.

You can see all transitions between 1900 and 2035 [here](https://nodatime.org/tzvalidate/generate?version=2019c&zone=America/Dawson) - that's using IANA 2019c data.

The [source data for America/Dawson](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/06b51ae816f19ab7bbe84882b3fbc2d4906e63a5/northamerica#L2477) shows that too:

```
Zone America/Dawson -9:17:40 -  LMT 1900 Aug 20
            -9:00   NT_YK   Y%sT    1973 Oct 28  0:00
            -8:00   NT_YK   P%sT    1980
            -8:00   Canada  P%sT
```

That shows that between 1900 and 1973 it's using the NT_YK rules, which are defined [just above](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/06b51ae816f19ab7bbe84882b3fbc2d4906e63a5/northamerica#L2422):

```
# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO  TYPE    IN  ON  AT  SAVE    LETTER/S
Rule    NT_YK   1918    only    -   Apr 14  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    NT_YK   1918    only    -   Oct 27  2:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1919    only    -   May 25  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    NT_YK   1919    only    -   Nov  1  0:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1942    only    -   Feb  9  2:00    1:00    W # War
Rule    NT_YK   1945    only    -   Aug 14  23:00u  1:00    P # Peace
Rule    NT_YK   1945    only    -   Sep 30  2:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1965    only    -   Apr lastSun 0:00    2:00    DD
Rule    NT_YK   1965    only    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1980    1986    -   Apr lastSun 2:00    1:00    D
Rule    NT_YK   1980    2006    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1987    2006    -   Apr Sun>=1  2:00    1:00    D
```

> and how to avoid this?

Pick a time zone that has the rules you want to observe, being aware that just because two time zones have the same current and *future* rules, that doesn't mean they've had the same rules in the past.